# How to enable a dynamic website to take input from less known languages?

Tags: web-applications, browser, unicode, encoding, web

How can a web developer enable a dynamic website to take input from non-Latin Unicode characters that are from less known languages? Is there a code I can add to allow such feature or do I have to develop custom plugins for the major browsers? What possible solutions exist specific to web development packages like (ASP.Net, php...)?

Answer (score 4):

You should use unicode encodings (eg UTF-8) for every part of the server that deals with strings/text. There can be multiple applications and connections involved which all need to be configured separately. For example:

- Web-server: Accept unicode parameters, serve content with a unicode charset (`charset=utf-8`)
- Server-side language: Manipulate strings with unicode. Open file streams, and database connections with unicode encodings.
- Database: Appropriate encodings are set for field contents.

Comment: Just an addition to @fgb's answer: when defining the database you has to set the type of every text field (like char, varchar and text) to the types that accept unicode (like nchar, nvarchar and ntext). Also every inline string in your sql sentences should be preceded by N (line `N'example string'`), even if it doesn't contains any special  character.